# Call a from a parent class inherited class method from within a child class

Tags: python, inheritance

How do I call a from a parent class inherited class method from within a child class in Python?

A minimum working example is:

```
class Parent:
    my_member_variable = 348627

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print("I made it from {} and my_member_variable = {}.".format(
                cls, cls.my_member_variable))


class Child(Parent):
    my_member_variable = 982374982
    cls.class_method()  # DOES NOT WORK! I want to have the result I
                        # made it from <class '__main__.Child'> and
                        # my_member_variable = 982374982.>>.
```

This unfortunately gives the error `NameError: name 'cls' is not defined`.

How can I call the class method `class_method`, which the class `Child` inherited from the class `Parent`, from within the class `Child` and at the same time use the `my_member_variable` from the class `Child` and not from the class `Parent`?

Comment: Why are you trying to call a method at class level?

Comment: The class that *will* be bound to `Child` doesn't even exist yet when you are trying to call the method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I am trying to generate class level data for several classes that are childs from the same parent class. The way in which this data is made is the same for all the child classes, so I denote it as a class method in the parent class. Or is there perhaps a better approach to this problem?

Comment: @chepner Aren't all the member variables and functions inherited from the parent class immediately after the `class Child(Parent)` statement? If not, when are they inherited and how can I call them at class level?

Comment: Inheritance is implemented solely by the attribute lookup process. You have no lookup yet, because `cls` doesn't exist. `class Child(Parent): ...` just means that `Parent` gets added to the method resolution order for `Child`, nothing else. When you try to access an attribute on `Child` or an instance of `Child`, *then* inheritance plays a part, of the requested attribute cannot be found in the instance  itself or in the definition of `Child`.

Comment: *Nothing* you do inside that `class` statement can refer to `<class '__main__.Child'>`, because that object doesn't exist until the very last step of evaluating the `class` statement, *after* the body has been evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the method before the class `Child` even exists. Your `class` statement (with the method call commented out for now)

```
class Child(Parent):

    my_member_variable = 982374982
    # cls.class_method()
```

is equivalent to

```
my_member_variable = 982374982
cls.class_method()
Child = type('Child', (Parent,), {'my_member_variable': my_member_variable})
del my_member_variable
```

The body of the `class` statement is evaluated in order to determine the contents of the 3rd argument passed to `type`. If you uncomment the method call, it's easy to see that `cls.class_method` is evaluated *before* `type` returns the new class which your name `cls` is intended to refer to.

Put another way, in the above code, `cls` is undefined. But it should be obvious that you can't simply say

```
my_member_variable = 982374982
cls = Child
cls.class_method()
Child = type('Child', (Parent,), {'my_member_variable': my_member_variable})
del my_member_variable
```

because `Child` isn't defined yet either, and the value you want to assign to `cls` is the return value of a call to `type` that hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Parent:
my_member_variable = 348627
@classmethod
def class_method(cls):
    print("I made it from {} and my_member_variable = {}.".format(cls, cls.my_member_variable))

class Child(Parent):
    my_member_variable = 982374982

Child.class_method()
```

Output:

```
I made it from <class '__main__.Child'> and my_member_variable = 982374982.
```

I think this is what you are trying to do. Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

You can use super().class_method() instead of cls.class_method from within the child class.

Comment: While its not, in theory, impossible to call `super` directly from the body of a `class` statement, you have to provide at least one argument first; the zero-argument form raises a `RuntimeError`.

Comment: You are right about the error. The explanation is provided by you in your post.